# arcpy doesn't save output from "Generate Points Along Lines" to "in_memory"

Tags: arcpy, in-memory, error-000840

I'm trying to run the tool "Generate Points Along Lines" like this:

```
arcpy.GeneratePointsAlongLines(inputFeature,r"in_memory\temp","DISTANCE","100 meters")
```

when setting the output as "in_memory", an error occurs:

> 000840 the value is not a workspace.

but when I'm running it from the Toolbox it works fine.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong or how to make it run using ArcPy?

Comment: Works when i try it with (obs +_mangement): `arcpy.GeneratePointsAlongLines_management("Lines123",r"in_memory\temp","DISTANCE","100 meters")`. How do you define inputFeature? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @BERA you should migrate that to answer as I think you hit the nail on the head. Also to compliment this suggest @segev look at the code sample of ANY tool in the help file and they will see that any tool called using arcpy is always references `arcpy.toolname_toolboxalias(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you need to add _management to the name of the tool.
For example:

```
arcpy.GeneratePointsAlongLines_management("Lines123",r"in_memory\temp","DISTANCE","100 meters")
```

This is working for me.